# Do nested for loops in python work unlike they do in C?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I use nested for loops in Python, the way we usually do in C?

I am working on a problem that takes three inputs and then a number. The program should return sets of 3 integers, each up to their respective values that we gave as input, whose sum is not equal to the fourth number we gave as input.

I tried using three nested for loops, each iterating over the range of three integer values we gave as input. But, my program stops after giving the first `[0,0,0]` combination only.

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
z = int(input())
n = int(input())
num_list=[]
for a in range(x):

    for b in range(y):

        for c in range(z):

            if a+b+c==n:
                continue
            else:
                num_list.append((a,b,c))
print(num_list)
```

If the inputs are `1, 1, 1, 2` then the program should return `[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]` but my output is`[(0,0,0)]`.

Comment: Range(1) is _exclusive_ the number 1, so it only yields 0. You want range(x+1) and so on.

Answer (score 3):

[`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) has a non-inclusive upper bound. `list(range(1))` is `[0]` - not `[0,1]`:

You get

```
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
```

if you change

```
for a in range(x+1):              # add 1 here
    for b in range(y+1):              # and here
        for c in range(z+1):              # and here
            # ect
```

You will still have tuples in your list - because you add tuples and not lists into it:

```
num_list.append((a,b,c))  # this adds a tuple (a,b,c) not a list [a,b,c]
```

---

You get the same result via list comprehension:

```
num_list= [(a,b,c) for a in range(x+1) for b in range(y+1) for c in range(z+1) 
           if a+b+c != n]
```